# Track webpage downloading progress

Tags: vb.net, stream

I'm using this piece of code for VB.NET to download the text from a website:

```
Dim Str As System.IO.Stream
        Dim srRead As System.IO.StreamReader
        Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/file.txt")
        Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse
        Str = resp.GetResponseStream
        srRead = New System.IO.StreamReader(Str)
```

It is just a text file, and is rather small, so it downloads really quickly. But I do believe that in the future the file will become considerably large. Is there a way to track the downloading progress from the above method?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the total length of your find in the `ContentLength` property of your `WebResponse` object. Once you have that, it's pretty easy to report progress based on the data you read from the `GetResponseStream`.