# How to download .exe file with progress bar - VB 2012

Tags: vb.net, download

I am trying to create an updater for my program which automatically download's the latest version of my program from the web. Now I want this process to be done using a progress bar (so when the download progress is at 50% the progress bar is half-way through). This is my code:

```
 Private Sub client_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Dim bytesIn As Double = Double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString())
    Dim totalBytes As Double = Double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString())
    Dim percentage As Double = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100

    client.Value = Int32.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString())
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim url As String = "MY DOWNLOAD LINK"
    'Download
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient
    AddHandler client.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf client_ProgressChanged
    AddHandler client.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf client_DownloadCompleted
    client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(url), "C:\Users\User\Desktop\BACKUP\TESTING\New folder\1.exe")
End Sub
End Class
```

Now I know that the place where the file is saved has been inputed manually by me , but I will change that later. My problem currently is that the file is not being downloaded. However when I change the DownloadFileAsync method to DownloadFile , my program downloads the file. However with the DownloadFile method I will not be able to use the progress bar to track the download progress. Any help is much appreciated :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Track webpage downloading progress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408345/track-webpage-downloading-progress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what you mean, when you say that the file isn't downloaded? You get an Error/Exception? Nothing happens at all? Did you place breakpoints, debug.prints etc?

With VS2012 and asyn/await you can put everything into one method an keep a "linear code-flow". Import System.Threading and System.Threading.Tasks

```
Private Async Function DownloadWithProgress(ByVal url As String, ByVal p As ProgressBar) As Task(Of Integer)

    Dim wc As Net.HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url), Net.HttpWebRequest)
    Dim resp = Await (New TaskFactory(Of Net.WebResponse)).StartNew(AddressOf wc.GetResponse)
    p.Value = 0
    p.Maximum = CInt(resp.ContentLength)
    Dim rqs = resp.GetResponseStream


    Dim bufsize As Integer = 1 << 16
    Dim buffer(bufsize) As Byte
    Dim got As Integer = 0
    Dim total As Integer = 0
    Do
        got = Await (New TaskFactory(Of Integer)).FromAsync(AddressOf rqs.BeginRead, AddressOf rqs.EndRead, buffer, 0, bufsize, Nothing)
        total += got
        Me.Label1.Text = "got: " & total.ToString
        p.Increment(got)
    Loop Until got = 0

    Return total

End Function
```

In this sample, the data from the web is downloaded into an array, but you can of course also write it into a file, or do whatever you want with the data.

Sample for usage:

```
Private running As Boolean = False
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If running Then
        MessageBox.Show("Cant you see, I'm working?")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        running = True
    End If

    Await DownloadWithProgress("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip", ProgressBar1)
    running = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment however when I execute your code I get the following errors: 
Error 1 Type 'Task' is not defined. C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb 3 97 WindowsApplication1

Comment: Error 2 Type 'TaskFactory' is not defined. C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb 6 31 WindowsApplication1
Error 3 Type 'TaskFactory' is not defined. C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb 17 30 WindowsApplication1

Comment: Error 4 'Await' can only be used when contained within a method or lambda expression marked with the 'Async' modifier. C:\Users\Milad\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb 39 9 WindowsApplication1

Comment: You need to import the needed namespaces; added info to post.